Can we customize the calendar heatmap to display week names on top of the calendar
I want to dislay week names(S M T W T F S) and instead of heatmap I want to display date of the month in calendar heatmap, I don't see any documents regarding this. Has anybody tried this? If tried please help me.
I tried changing the src file but didn't work.
